# ffmpeg (two audio stream + 1 video stream) -vf/-af/-filter and -filter_complex cannot be used together for the same stream

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to capture the screen video and two audio stream, one from mic, and the other one from analog monitor.

```bsh
    ffmpeg -video_size "$__screen_size__" \
        -framerate 50 \
        -thread_queue_size 512 -f x11grab -i :0.0+0,0 \
        -thread_queue_size 512 -f pulse -i "$__input_mic__" \
        -thread_queue_size 512 -f pulse -i "$__output_monitor__" \
        -filter_complex amerge \
        -ac 2 \
        -vcodec libx264rgb -crf 0 -preset:v ultrafast \
        -acodec pcm_s16le \
        -af aresample=async=1:first_pts=0 \
        -async 1 \
        -y \
        "$__output__"
```

The problem is ffmpeg complains about using two filter simultaneously for one stream:

```
Filtergraph 'aresample=async=1:first_pts=0' was specified through the
 -vf/-af/-filter option for output stream 0:0, which is fed from a complex filtergraph.
-vf/-af/-filter and -filter_complex cannot be used together for the same stream.
```

The script below (only one audio stream form mic) however works perfectly fine, when I don't have to merge audio streams

```bsh
    ffmpeg -video_size "$__screen_size__" \
        -framerate 50 \
        -thread_queue_size 512 -f x11grab -i :0.0+0,0 \
        -thread_queue_size 512 -f pulse -i "$__input_mic__" \
        -vcodec libx264rgb -crf 0 -preset:v ultrafast \
        -acodec pcm_s16le \
        -af aresample=async=1:first_pts=0 \
        -async 1 \
        -y \
        "$__output__"
```

basically removing:

```bsh
        -thread_queue_size 512 -f pulse -i "$__output_monitor__" \
        -filter_complex amerge \
        -ac 2 \
```

If I remove `-af aresample=async=1:first_pts=0` and keep the above then the audio and video won't be synchronized.

Basically I want to merge audio streams without introducing any latency.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify all filters in a single filtergraph.

`-filter_complex [1]aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[a];[2]aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[b];[a][b]amerge`

Comment: This gives the following error: `The following filters could not choose their formats: Parsed_amerge_2
Consider inserting the (a)format filter near their input or output.
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Input/output error
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #2:0`

Comment: FFmpeg version?

Comment: ffmpeg version n4.4